# Build Error with CalcOpticalFlowFarneback Function -> OpenCV -> C Language - Eclipse -> MacOSX

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, opencv, opticalflow

i have to do a program using C Language and OpenCV Libreries for a project,
I followed the guide for the installation for MACOSX on this site:
[OpenCV Installation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port)

I used Mac Port for the Istallation.

I use Eclipse to program,
Now when i try to compile this program, i get a Build Error and i think that it depends to CalcOpticalFlowFarneback() Function.

This is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cv.h>
    #include <highgui.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>


int main(){



    CvCapture* webcam = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    IplImage*prev=NULL;
    IplImage*next=NULL;
    char scelta;

    /*INIZIALIZZAZIONE FUNZIONE RAND*/

    srand(time(NULL));


    double pyr_scale=0.5; 
    int levels=1;
    int winsize=3; 
    int iterations=10;
    int poly_n=5; 
    double poly_sigma=1.1;
    int flags=0;

    sleep(2);

    if (!webcam){
    /* Exit with an error */
        puts("Attenzione! si è verificato un Errore in Fase di Attivazione della WebCam. Preghiamo di Riprovare!");
        return -1;
    }


    while (1) {

        prev = cvQueryFrame(webcam);//primi 8-bit single-channel immagine in ingresso
        next = cvQueryFrame(webcam);// immagine secondo ingresso della stessa dimensione e lo stesso tipo prev.

        CvSize isize = cvSize(80,80);
        IplImage *flow = cvCreateImage(isize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1); //immagine computerizzata che ha le stesse dimensioni e tipo CV_32FC2 prev
        if ((prev) && (next)) {



            cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev,next,flow,pyr_scale,levels,winsize,iterations,poly_n,poly_sigma,flags);

            scelta=cvWaitKey(20);
            if((char)scelta == 27){

                break;
            }


        }


    }

    cvDestroyWindow("VIDEO SORVEGLIANZA");
    cvReleaseCapture(&webcam);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error Log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback", referenced from:_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cattura_foto] Error 1
```

And I want to specify that if i remove the cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback Function i do not have any problems.

Thank you,

manu.web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"undefined symbol" means that you have not linked against the proper library, or you have, but the library is for the wrong architecture (e.g. a 32-bit library while your machine is 64-bit).

You need to check the linking flags and paths, and the library installation path.

If you can get the linker log in Eclipse, and/or the command line that got passed to the linker, you can repeat the linking command from a terminal and see if you get a more helpful message (such as "library not found"). Or you can try running the `make` command from the terminal and do the same.

Editing the Makefile, you might find that some commands are prepended with the "@" symbol, which prevents them from being output (their output is visible, the command itself is not). You can usually safely remove the @'s and get a more verbose output.

Another possibility is that there is a name mangling error, and the "_" prefix to the function should not be there. I am not too familiar with Eclipse though, so I can't follow you there. But see e.g. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/783606/ ; you *might* have built OpenCV with the wrong options, so that now it is not compatible with your code. Which is strange, seeing as how you call other OpenCV functions without problems; but maybe you built OpenCV in two steps?

In general (this is not limited to OpenCV!) you will have a build command such as

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib main.c -o Cattura_foto2 \
-lopencv_core.2.4.3 \
-lopencv_imgproc.2.4.3 \
-lopencv_highgui.2.4.3 \
-lopencv_gpu.2.4.3
```

and an error complaining of an undefined symbol:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback"
```

This means that you are linking with the libraries openvc_core.2.4.3 etc. and the linker cannot find the symbol "_cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback".

Locate those libraries on your computer, and run (from Terminal) the following command against all the libraries you found. **Note: your path will probably be different. I have /usr/lib64**.

```
for lib in /usr/lib64/libopencv_*; do 
    echo "Examining $lib..."
    strings $lib | grep -i cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
done
```

You ought to see something like:

```
Examining /usr/lib/libopencv_pippo_pluto...
Examining /usr/lib/libopencv_blah_blah...
...
Examining /usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so...
cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
Examining /usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so.2.4...
cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
Examining /usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so.2.4.3...
cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
```

The reason for the multiple matches is that libraries exist in multiple symbolic copies.

To be sure, let's inspect the library:

```
nm -D /usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so.2.4 | grep Farneback

0000000000027e50 T cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback
```

Now we know two important things:

1. The symbol is *really* called `cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback`. Your GCC is complaining it doesn't find the symbol `_cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback`, with an underscore. You either built the library incorrectly or you are missing a `-fno-leading-underscore` option to GCC.

But if that were the case, **no OpenCV2 symbols** at all would be recognized. So, I'm betting on #2:

1. The symbol is in **libopencv_video.so.2.4.3**, and there is no reference to that library in your build command! You ought to have **-lopencv_video.2.4.3** or something like that. Verify your makefile and options.

Let me know how it goes - and *in bocca al lupo*.

Comment: I used this command line  > sudo port install opencv
to build OpenCV 2.1.0 in 64-bit.  and i specified on project property the right path opt/local/lib  and each specific library:   opencv_gpu.2.4.3 so i mean what's wrong?    i do not understand..
opencv_core.2.4.3
opencv_highgui.2.4.3
opencv_imgproc.2.4.3

Comment: I don't know either: cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback is indeed in the library. Editing answer.

Comment: i tried to compile with terminal and  I get as follow:  MacBook-Pro-di-emanuele:cattura_foto2 emanuelegragnoli$ gcc -I/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib main.c  -o Cattura_foto2  -lopencv_core.2.4.3 -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.3 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.3 -lopencv_gpu.2.4.3
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvCalcOpticalFlowFarneback", referenced from:
      _main in ccYUFnom.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I think we might have found the problem (actually, I should have done this earlier). I included a general troubleshooting procedure for these cases in the answer.